# Пробел перед тире

Tags: оформление-текста

Нужен ли пробел перед тире после запятой или точки (в случаях прямой речи или в библиогр. описании)? В разных источниках ответы разные. Или единого правила нет?

Comment: Если метка указана неточно, исправьте, пож-та.

Comment: @grizzly А Вы уверены, что имеется в виду библиогр. описание? Я подумала о библейском (поэтому текст и не меняла). Надо бы у автора уточнить.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, я уверен. В библиографическом описании используются так называемые "условные разделительные знаки", которые по форме не отличаются от знаков препинания, из-за чего часто возникает путаница. Что бы я уточнил у автора, так это по поводу "разных источников" с разными ответами: интересно, что понимается под "источниками".

Comment: Извиняюсь за некорректное сокращение, имел ввиду действительно библиографическое. "Разные источники": некоторые из них приведены в ответе.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки оставил в метках Типографику.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужен.

Тире без пробелов ставится только между датами:

> **[Вопрос № 291716](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291716)**
>
> Добрый вечер. Хочу уточнить: при цифровых обозначениях в значениях «от... до» и «или» ставится тире без
>   пробелов?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Между цифрами ставится тире без пробелов, напр.: 10–13, 3–4.

Если под "разными источниками" Вы подразумевали [вот это](https://pixelplus.ru/studio/stat/pravila-postanovki-probela-ryadom-so-znakami-prepinaniya/):

> В некоторых руководствах по типографскому набору также указывается,
>   что пробел не ставится, если тире идёт после точки или запятой, но при
>   работе с большинством современных шрифтов этот совет скорее вреден,

то данный источник указует на прямую "вредность" указаний "некоторых руководств".

Следует также вспомнить, что в языке не существует понятий длинное или короткое тире (это вопрос дизайна текста), просто: тире.

**[Вопрос № 286781](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286781)**

> Дорогие сотрудники Грамоты, пожалуйста, ответьте на заданный мной
>   сегодня вопрос о якобы существующем знаке "короткое тире без пробелов
>   между словами". Это нужно не мне, я-то понимаю, что такого знака не
>   бывает. Но вы -- единственная инстанция, на которую я могу сослаться!
>   Впрочем, даже при наличии ответа от вас некоторые авторы заявляют, что
>   Институт русского языка для них не авторитет... Но все-таки я еще
>   надеюсь на вас.
>
> Пожалуйста, сформулируйте где-нибудь четкий запрет на тире без
>   пробелов между словами в русском тексте, чтобы можно было на вас
>   ссылаться! Еще 10 лет назад никого бы не посетила идея изобразить
>   где-либо такое чудо, как два слова, соединенные при помощи тире без
>   пробелов. Поэтому нигде нельзя найти запрет. Но необходимость в нем
>   назрела!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В реестр кодифицированных знаков препинания входит только два вида
>   горизонтальных черточек: тире и дефис. В этом можно убедиться,
>   обратившись к «Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г. –
>   своего рода орфографической конституции. Достаточно посмотреть на
>   оглавление. Никто из авторитетных специалистов по пунктуации (А. Б.
>   Шапиро, Д. Э. Розенталь, Н. С. Валгина) не добавляли в этот перечень
>   какие-либо другие знаки препинания.
>
> Тире должно отделяться пробелами от предшествующего и последующего
>   текста. Ср. с примерами из правил 1956 г. и академического справочника
>   2006 г.: физический закон Бойля – Мариотта, встреча с гостями
>   Олимпиады – иностранцами.
>
> Единственный случай, когда тире не отбивается **пробелами, – позиция**
>   между цифрами.

(Я выделила в последней строке тире Грамоты.ру, отбитое от запятой.)

---

Википедия уточняет:

**[Типографика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)**

> Тире отбивается пробелами по следующим правилам:
>
> - после тире, стоящих в начале абзаца (при прямой речи или в списках), ставится неразрывный пробел обычного размера;
> - тире, обозначающее диапазон значений, границы которого заданы числами (1941—1945, XVI—XVII), пробелами не отбивают;
> - вокруг всех остальных тире предписывается ставить узкие (2 пункта) пробелы, причём перед тире пробел должен быть неразрывным. Однако
>     из-за технических ограничений компьютерного набора нередко вместо
>     укороченных пробелов ставят обычные; такая практика допускается и
>     официально «в изданиях оперативной полиграфии»;
>
>   - **тире, идущее за запятой или точкой, по академическим правилам набирается без пробела**, однако в современных шрифтах такой набор
>       выглядит некрасиво и от этого требования практически отказались.

Comment: Можно сказать, что убедили в необходимости пробела. Спасибо!