# Пробелы вокруг тире в составных названиях и двойных именах

Tags: тире, дефис, пробелы, дефис-тире

Как расставлять пробелы в составных названиях вокруг тире и в двойных фамилиях вокруг дефиса? Одни корректоры издательств требуют вокруг тире вставлять шпации по 2 пункта, другие говорят, что пробелы вообще не нужны. Кто прав? Вокруг дефиса пробелы вроде бы не ставят. Составные названия какого-нибудь учения или учреждения -- это термины, составленные из имен разных людей (например, уравнение Фоккера -- Планка). Двойная фамилия -- имя одного человека (например, Немирович-Данченко).

Все эти вопросы для меня обострились при работе с корректурой двухтомного учебника, два тома которого смотрели два разных корректора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет именно о публикации, то правых в этом вопросе нет. Каждое издательство руководствуется тем или иным справочником/мануалом, который и диктует оформление.

Если вы получили противоречащие ответы от корректоров из одного издательства, то стоит поднять этот вопрос с их руководством—либо один из них плохо владеет используемым компанией стандартом, либо эта ситуация стандартом не регулируется (что весьма странно). Тогда необходимо, чтобы было принято административное решение о том, как подобные элементы должны оформляться в этом издательстве.

В реальности вы можете найти примеры публикаций использующих: дефис; тире без пробелов; тире с обычными пробелами; тире с пробелами в 2 пт; т.н. "среднее тире" (en-dash) без пробелов; среднее тире с пробелами.

В своде "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" (самый близкий к единому стандарту справочник), насколько мне известно, нет упоминаний использовании дефиса или тире в функции смыслового соединения двух собственных имен.

Comment: Естественно, я обсудил работу корректоров с редактором издательства. Про дефис  в двойных фамилиях информация получена от одного  энтузиаста-перфекциониста. Я нашел её подтверждение на стр. 103 в книге Шульмейстера Ручной набор.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на обсуждении. Я туда добавил описание реализации различных тире в LaTeX'е.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, *в реальности* можно найти какое угодно оформление сложных имен и сложных названий (законов, правил, уравнений, чисел, формул, теорем...).
И, конечно же, в "Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации" **есть** разъяснения для таких особенных случаев.

[§124](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)
*Пишутся **через дефис**:

Двойные (редко тройные) фамилии (в том числе включающие в свой состав псевдонимы, а также присвоенные за особые заслуги почетные именования), напр.: Римский-Корсаков, Немирович-Данченко, Мамин-Сибиряк, Мельников-Печерский, Сергеев-Ценский, Новиков-Прибой, Потёмкин-Таврический, Муравьёв-Амурский, Семёнов-Тян-Шанский, Овчина-Оболенский-Телепнев, Склодовская-Кюри, Тулуз-Лотрек, Шолом-Алейхем, Андерсен-Нексе.*

[§20](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)
*Тире ставится между двумя (и более) именами собственными, совокупностью которых называется какое-либо учение, явление и т. п.: закон **Бойля — Мариотта**; матч **Каспаров — Карпов**.*

Стоит, наверно, напомнить, что дефис — это орфографический знак (то есть знак для *одного слова*; он не предусматривает никаких пробелов).
Тире — это пунктуационный знак, требующий пробелов (*закон Бойля и Мариотта* — тире ставится на месте пропуска союза "и"; был еще в советское время вопрос на сообразительность: «Как звали жену Бойля — Мариотта?»).

Для примера:
закон Гей-Люссака, [уравнение Менделеева — Клапейрона](http://ens.tpu.ru/POSOBIE_FIS_KUSN/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.%20%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/01-5.htm), формула Эйлера — Маклорена, теорема Ньютона — Лейбница, закон Джоуля — Ленца, лемма Шепли — Фолкмана, задача Минковского — Александрова.

Дополнительно (мнение [Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%20&start=75)):
**Вопрос № 246834**
Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется "система Эльконина-Давыдова":
через дефис, через тире и нужны ли пробелы (Эльконина — Давыдова)?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Необходимо тире (с пробелами), т. к. это две разные фамилии: *система Эльконина — Давыдова*. Через дефис пишутся части одной фамилии: *Римский-Корсаков*.

**После комментария** (11. 01. 2021)

*Дама, вероятно, не прочла вопрос.*
Дама **невероятно** внимательно прочла вопрос.

*Вопрос был о пробелах вокруг тире.*
Ответ на этот вопрос дан — пробелы вокруг тире необходимы. [Посмотрите оформление примеров в §20 и четкую рекомендацию "Грамоты": необходимо тире (с пробелами).]

Думаю, что неотделение тире пробелами никак нельзя отнести к авторской пунктуации ([Чем авторское решение отличается от факультативного?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462999/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/463000#463000)). Я бы посчитала такое написание ошибкой (в особенности — в печатном тексте).

[Различие тире и дефиса](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0/) (Типографика. Оформление текстов)

**После "отминусовки"** (15. 01. 2021)

Я **невероятно** рада, — честное слово! — что Вы наконец-то смогли воспользоваться своим правом **поставить минус** за правильный ответ.

Вдогонку: есть на сайте *похожий **вопрос-ответ*** с высоким рейтингом, который никто не оспаривает. Есть правила, есть примеры, есть мнение сообщества — чего ж еще? (Или тоже минусовать будете?)

[**Пробел перед тире**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441791/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5/441794#441794)

Comment: Дама, вероятно, не прочла вопрос. Вопрос был о пробелах вокруг тире. Жаль, что пока не могу поставить ей минус.

Comment: Удивительное молчаливое _**минусовательное**_ дело! **Все** словари и справочники (повторю — все!) говорят, что тире **всегда** отбивается пробелами (за исключением числовых промежутков: 1941—1945; 2—14; 1853—1856). P. S. Думаю, что надо сделать глобальный перерыв — и "упирабельность", и жемчуга́ закончились.