# Знаки препинания при прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, вставная-конструкция, цитирование

*Вот кусок предложения из письма женщины: «Там же похоронена жена его, Дубовицкая Анна Ивановна (1915 – 1991 г. р.)», – пишет она.*
Не влияет ли сокращение в скобке, а именно наличие точки после «р», на постановку запятой после кавычки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу в Вашем предложении такие неточности.

Первая. То, что приведено в кавычках, является **цитированием** (Вы сами об этом говорите: "Вот кусок предложения из письма женщины"). Тогда фраза "пишет она" не нужна.

Вторая. **(1915 – 1991 г. р.)** Я думаю, что Вы хотели указать в скобках годы жизни, а написали **г. р.** — годы рождения. Так не бывает.

Третья. Между числами ставится короткое тире без пробелов: (1915–1991).

Можно оформить так:
*Вот кусок предложения из письма женщины: «Там же похоронена жена его, Дубовицкая Анна Ивановна (1915–1991)».*

По сути собственно вопроса:

> Знаки препинания, которые стоят на месте «разрыва» предложения вставной конструкцией, выделяемой скобками, помещаются после скобок: *У Саввы, пастуха **(он барских пас овец),** вдруг убывать овечки стали* (Крылов).

> После закрывающей скобки ставится знак препинания, требуемый условиями контекста, независимо от того, какой знак стоит перед закрывающей скобкой.

Знаки препинания внутри скобок **никак** не влияют на пунктуацию в самом предложении. Каждый из них ставится на основании своих правил — это называется [сочетанием знаков препинания](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/).
Если абстрагироваться от неточностей, то знаки в предложении поставлены правильно: точка внутри скобок — скобка — кавычки — запятая — тире.

[Вставные предложения и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_26.htm) (примечание)
[Скобки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175)

**P. S.** Вот пример (предложение [из моего ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463012/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85/463018#463018)) — чего только нет в скобках, но на правилах цитирования это не сказывается.
«Тире — это пунктуационный знак, требующий пробелов (*закон Бойля и Мариотта* — тире ставится на месте пропуска союза "и"; был еще в советское время вопрос на сообразительность: "Как звали жену Бойля — Мариотта?")», — так написано в ответе.

Comment: @shampar Извините, но я откатила Вашу правку. 1. Посмотрите вот здесь: _“Вы” или “вы” — как правильно в ответе на вопрос?_ (https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/%d0%92%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81) И если уж менять "Вы" на "вы", то — везде. 2. Графически наличие пробела – признак слова. Следует разделять все сокращения и цифры... (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/90-data)

Comment: 1. Вроде бы менял везде... Объяснюсь: наши тексты всегда обращены вовне, хотя и по конкретному адресу. Обращение на вы с прописной не должно смущать (коробить) никого. А оно как работает? — намекает всем на чтение чужой переписки. 2. «Написали г. р. — годы рождения.» Здесь «г. р.» — никак не годы и второе: полноценный пробел в нашем редакторе лучше не ставить, т.к. он разносит знаки по строкам, а неразрывного пробела в нём нету.