# Какой корень в слове "камень"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

Все сайты, предлагающие морфемный разбор слов, указывают, что в слове *камень* корень *-камен*. Но у нас же имеется такое слово, как *камушек*, где выделяется корень *-кам*? Так правда ли, что в этих двух, как мне казалось, однокоренных словах разные корни? Чем это можно объяснить? Заранее благодарю!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Словообразовательный словарь **Тихонова**: камень (непроизводн.)  – камеш/ек, **чередование** Н/Ш, суффикс ЕК; камень (непроизводн.) – кам/ушек, **усечение** основы на ЕН, суффикс УШЕК.
2. В Толковом словаре словообразовательных единиц **Ефремовой** информация аналогичная.
3. **Чередование  Н/Ш** – это не редкость в русском языке: ремень – ремешок, корень – корешок,  карман – кармашек.
4. **Вывод.**  При образовании  слов **корневая основа может меняться**, поэтому некорректно считать, что корень – это всегда наименьшая часть родственных слов.

Comment: Вот ларчик и открылся!

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Помните у Шекспира: "Неладно что-то в датском королевстве... " Но, может быть, мне просто так показалось.

Comment: Нет, Sharon, Вам не показалось. Это хорошо, здо́рово, что приходят новые участники (пытливые, с интересными рассуждениями, **с умением** отстаивать свою точку зрения). Но иногда дело доходит до абсурда. Вот, напомню: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463012/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85/463018#463018. Бесполезно.

Comment: Блестящий ответ! Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

> Какой корень в слове “камень”?

Хоть ответ на этот вопрос давно уже здесь дан и давно уже принят, рискну всё же вновь поднять его.

По-моему, возможны различные подходы к членению слова *камень* на морфемы.

Согласно "Морфемно-орфографическому словарю" А. Н. Тихонова в этом слове корень ***камен'-*** и нулевое окончание.

Но вряд ли будет ошибкой считать корнем в слове ***кам**ень* при сравнении его со словом ***кам**ушек* часть ***кам-.***

**Ефремова** и **Кузнецова** в "Словаре морфем русского языка" в слове ***камень*** именно такой корень и выделяют.

И даже, сравнивая слова *ремень* и *камень*, считают возможным и слово *ремень* членить на морфемы:

> …В слове ***ремешок*** с точки зрения морфемного анализа, учитывая не
> только литературный язык, но и диалекты, и просторечие, можно...
> произвести членение ***рем-ешок***, где корень ***-рем-*** выделяется
> благодаря сравнению с диалектными ***ремье, ремуха***, а также по
> аналогии с корнями ***-кам-*** или ***-греб-*** (ср. ***камень*** и
> ***камушек, гребу*** и ***гребешок***)…

Comment: Не зря рискнули!

Answer (score 2):

Слово *камушек* это альтернативная форма слова *камешек*, в котором, как правило, выделяется корень *камеш-*.

Этимология дальше прослеживается к реконструкции протославянского **kamy*, которая в нашей, восточной, ветке принимает форму *камꙑ*.

Однако *-ен* присутствует и в балтийских языках, с которыми расхождение началось раньше, поэтому четко сказать когда эта часть вошла в корень сложно. Например, в латвийском слово имеет форму *akmens* (в славянских языках произошла метатеза первых двух букв).

Если прослеживать вплоть до реконструкции прото-индо-европейского (4500–6500 лет назад), то восстановленный предок неоднозначен: **h₂éḱmō* либо **h₂éḱmen*, так что, возможно, *-ен* можно считать неотъемлемой частью слова уже с тех пор.

Ну и интереса ради отмечу, что эти формы происходят от корневого слова **h₂éḱ*, что восстановлено в значении "острый". Кстати, само слово *острый* прослеживается до этого же корня. Другие "однокоренные" слова: *осте́н* (шип), *осе́ть* (конструкция для сушки или хранилище для собранных семян) и *оселок* (шлифовальный камень).

Comment: Почему выделяется корень камеш-? Какой корень в камушке? Однокоренное ли это слово _камню_? Не могли бы вы ответить на эти вопросы?